# Alamofire for swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I was using alamofire 2.0.4 with swift 2.2 in xcode 7. Now i have upgraded my xcode to version 8 but this version of alamofire is not working anymore with either swift 2.3 or swift3. Is it not possible to use swift3 with alamofire? One important note here is I have to support ios8.

Comment: What is the configuration of your PodFile? `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'` is compatible Swift 3, did you do a `pod update`?

Comment: @Larme Yes I have used the same and did *pod update* but this Alamofire 4.0 is forcing to use ios10. In my case I need to support ios8.

Comment: According to https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#requirements 4.x supports iOS 9, but won't supports iOS8. And you can't do it with Swift 3 apparently.